# process duplication

Tags: process, linux-kernel

how to create a process at kernel level? As the functions do_fork and copy_process are static we cannot use them, so is there any way we could use their functionalities or do I have to implement functions similar to do_fork and copy_process to get the work done?

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=linux+fork

Comment: Maybe its best if you can describe more on why you need to create a process in the kernel space ? Kernel space threads are mostly required for for performing certain asynchronous tasks, for more info search for like flush,ksoftirqd,migration,etc...